# How to close a 'toggle' from another function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

If div.msg_head is clicked then .msg_row slides down using animate which this is working in my example.  My problem is that I am trying to write a function that will close all message panes before sliding down a second message that was clicked.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rZR5y/2/

Comment: id 'MESSAGE' and 'MESSAGE2' in your demo part of the message... or?

Comment: no that was just sample data... its inside the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine used of `id` and `class` atrribute to achive something like : http://jsfiddle.net/toopay/pUYpU/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that route... I guess i have been at the computer to long today...  this will work!  Its very short code too which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that you're trying to slideUp all other panes before sliding down a new one. This way only one pane will stay open.

Easy enough: Don't use toggle.

```
var $allMail = $(".msg_head");
$allMail.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.hasClass('opened') ) {
        $this.removeClass('opened').slideUp();
    } else {
        // assuming 'body' is the class of the div you want to show/hide
        $allMail.removeClass('opened').find('.body').slideUp();
        $this.addClass('opened').find('.body').slideDown();
    }
);
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.
Cheers!

Comment: The problem with this method is that slideDown and slideUp does not specify the height to change so it doesn't slide down.  So when you click the header twice it makes it disappear... I want the header to stay there but the message to slide down below... like my previous example...  http://jsfiddle.net/zAcpQ/2/

Comment: possibly some problem with your css? slideDown will slide your div down to its "natural" height. You shouldn't need to specify the 300px. If you need to, then mention it in css, and jquery will take care of it when you slideDown it.

Answer (score 1):

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/KM7Y3/)

- leave opened all messages
- calculate each message area height
- write heights to .data() for each message area
- close areas
- do the magic on click!

jQuery:

```
    $('.m_short_msg').each(function(e) {
        var h = $(this).height();
        $(this).data('height', h);
    });

    $('.m_short_msg').css({height: '19px'});

    $('.msg_row').click(function() {
        var d = $(this).find('.m_short_msg');
        check = (d.height() === d.data('height')) ?
                d.animate({height: '19px'}) :
                ( $('.m_short_msg').animate({height: '19px'}) ) ( d.animate({height: d.data('height')}) ) ;
    });
```

**EDIT**
Using .animate() you can add many animation effects to your elements from the jQuery UI.

With this script you can even CLOSE an opened message by clicking on it! So I find this one more 'user friendly'.

Another '+' of this script is that actually allow the user to see the first line of the message itself... for reference. And that is also UserFriendly™

---

If you have plans to have a 'message title' instead of showing the first line of the message you can do this:

### [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/KM7Y3/1/)

```
$('.msg_row').click(function() {
    var d = $(this).find('.msg');
    check = (d.is(':visible')) ? d.slideUp() : ($('.msg').slideUp())(d.slideDown());
});
```

It also checks for opened messages and has the ability to CLOSE the opened one if clicked again.

Comment: Thanks for the help! +!  I like the second one the best, its much easier to work with.

Comment: If you use this solution, would you mind to recommend it to all the people who will search for a solution to a similar problem - by accepting this answer. For using `ternary operators` to create an accordion - is definitely the best praxis. (Thanks for the vote-up, jason)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use accordin. I think it suitable for you and its very nice:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: The problem with that is you can't customize the "header" I need 3 rows on the header.  Plus, I prefer to write my own code, so I don't have to include more long js plugins... The according requires that you have jquery core, and jquery widget...